# Deleting time series rows that have too many consequitive equal values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series, namely a pandas.DataFrame with one column (containing the values) and the index (containing the timestamps). There are many values with 0 and I want to check for consecutive 0s. If there are too many 0 one after the other, I want to delete the 0s that are too much.

For example, if  I allow 0 only for 5 seconds, then I want all rows that represent time spans more than 5 seconds of 0s to be reduced to the first 5 seconds of 0s:

```
              value
time
12:01:01.001  1
12:01:01.002  0
12:01:01.004  6
12:01:01.010  4
12:01:03.010  0
12:01:05.010  0
12:01:08.010  0
12:01:10.010  0
12:01:10.510  0
12:01:11.101  3
12:01:12.101  3
12:01:15.101  0
```

should become

```
              value
time
12:01:01.001  1
12:01:01.002  0
12:01:01.004  6
12:01:01.010  4
12:01:03.010  0
12:01:05.010  0
12:01:08.010  0
12:01:11.101  3
12:01:12.101  3
12:01:15.101  0
```

#### Possible Solution

A possible solution would loop through the DataFrame having two variables: The first remembering when the first 0 of after a non-0 and the second iterating further until the time (e.g. 5sec) is exceeded. Then the first variables at the second variables position and the second moves until it reaches a non-0. All the zeros between the first and the second variable are deleted.

This is probably very efficient in C, but in Python, using a library is probably faster. **How do I do this elegantly with a Python library?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using pandas groupby.
Updating answer to show how to apply filter based on one column of dataframe.

**IMPORT DATA**

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

inp_str = u"""
time value
12:01:01.001 1
12:01:01.002 0
12:01:01.004 6
12:01:01.010 4
12:01:03.010 0
12:01:05.010 0
12:01:08.010 0
12:01:10.010 0
12:01:10.510 0
12:01:11.101 3
12:01:12.101 3
12:01:15.101 0
"""
frame = pd.read_csv(StringIO(inp_str), sep = " ").set_index('time')

# make sure we have a datetime index
frame.index = pd.to_datetime(frame.index)

# EDIT: ADD ANOTHER COLUM
frame = frame.assign(other = range(len(frame)))  

# EDIT: REPLACE ts with the relevant column
ts = frame['value']   

# Everything else remain unchanged!

# Group by consecutive values `ts != ts.shift()`
out = ts.groupby([(ts != ts.shift()).cumsum(), ts])

# for all sequences of zeros, identify where more than 5 seconds passed from beginning of sequence

def seconds_elapsed(ts):
    return ts.index.map(lambda x: (x - ts.index[0]).total_seconds())

to_drop = [group.index[np.where(map(lambda x: x>5, seconds_elapsed(group)))]
           for key, group in out if key[1] == 0]
# Collapse everything to flat list of dates
to_drop = reduce(lambda x, y: x.union(y), to_drop)
# Remove from dataframe
frame.drop(to_drop)
```

In order to apply multiple filters, there can be two situations:

1. Apply filters based on values in the original dataframe: For each filtering column, apply procedure above without overwriting the original dataframe, but always creating a new one. To have the final result, do an inner joins of the dataframes filtered by one column at the time
2. Apply filters consecutively: use the approach above for each filtering column, every time overwriting the original dataframe (order matters!)

Comment: Wow, that answer is mighty impressive. Regarding your first solution: Why are your writing `ts.loc[:]` instead of `ts`?

Comment: Fair point, ts works and is cleaner. I think in an earlier version I was using a dataframe and I needed to have a 1-dimensional grouper, hence I might have done something like df.loc[:, 0]...I will edit answer

Comment: Actually it might be useful to be able to run this on a dataframe, in case there are some more columns accompanied. Can you add a solution for this too? I did not want the example to be convoluted that's why I only mentioned the value column, but said it is a DataFrame.

Comment: Would you apply this filtering based on one column of a dataframe (with more columns) or do you want this filter to be applied to multiple columns of the same dataframe?

Comment: If you could show how to do it for one filtering column that would be great. If you can additionally show how to do it for multiple columns as filter that would be truly awesome.

Comment: I have added the answer if you filter according to one column of frame. I think multiple filters is a bit tricky as the order matters. It would be different to filter according to each column of the original dataframe or to do consecutive filterings.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? I tried and got expected output

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. Forget it.

Comment: I have added explanation on how to apply this for multiple filters in the same dataframe. Does this solve your question?